# Relative Path Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Our web application allows users to specify their own "slugs" which can include relative paths e.g. /somedir/some-file.htm.

In our routing configuration we need to ensure that only valid slugs (with segments) are supported.

The regex I am using is:

```
(^[a-z0-9])([a-z0-9-/]+)([a-z0-9])$
```

This means:

- A valid slug will match e.g. some-file.htm
- A valid slug with segments (relative path) will match e.g. somedir/subdir/some-file.htm
- Absolute URLs will NOT match e.g. /somedir/some-file.htm
- Trailing / or - will not match e.g. -slug-

Unfortunately it also means that double slashes will match e.g. somedir//subdir//some-file.htm because my expression is allowing one or more slashes.

How can I change it to allow zero or more slashes between segments.

I thought that:

```
(^[a-z0-9])(/?[a-z0-9-]+/?)([a-z0-9])$
```

would work but it does not.

Comment: it should be noted that depending on your filesystem, any character except `/` and `\0` can be considered to be a valid character in a filename.  This is including UTF specific characters and even ASCII Control Codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(/[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$`

EDIT: Use this one if you like the first regex:

`^(?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-)(/(?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-))*$`

It looks messy and complicated, but it seems to be correct per your spec.

`[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?`

Matches a single name.  Ignoring `/`s for the moment.

Then the rest of it is a single slash followed by that same thing again.

As mentioned in Karoly's answer, this does not include literal periods, for instance "some-file.htm" will not match the regex I wrote.

If this is desired behavior then you'll actually want:

`^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-\.]*[a-z0-9])?(/[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-\.]*[a-z0-9])?)*$`

Finally, if you want to allow literal periods in only the last section then you'll want:

`^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(/[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*(/[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-\.]*[a-z0-9])?)?$`

EDIT:

A thought occurs that this can be simplified a bit using lookaheads and behinds.

`^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(/[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*(/[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-\.]*[a-z0-9])?)?$`

becomes:

`^(?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-)(/(?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-))*(/(?!-\.)[a-z0-9-\.]+(?<!-\.))?$`

Comment: Your first regex meets all of my requirements. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably take the version with lookaheads and behinds.  I'll edit it in for the first one.  It's quite a bit more maintainable.

Comment: More maintainable but more complicated. Didn't even know you could do this with regex :)

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(^[a-z0-9]+)(/[a-z0-9-]+)*([a-z0-9])$
```

note: I don't see `.` in your regexp.

Personally I would separately test the first and last characters, that makes the regexp a lot simpler and more usable.

Comment: this works for the double slash requirement but it does not match a standard slug e.g. "this-is-a-test". We don't allow "." in our slugs.

Comment: Think maybe it should be `(^[a-z0-9])(/?[a-z0-9-]+)*([a-z0-9])$` ?

Comment: @Ben Foster: why is that any better?

Comment: This would falsely match: "this/-is-a-test"

Comment: hmm..yes. though it's a valid directory/file name on linux

Answer (score 0):

Check for valid path (relative or absolute. the dot is for hidden folders):

`^([a-z]:)*(\/*(\.*[a-z0-9]+\/)*(\.*[a-z0-9]+))`

Answer (score 0):

My requirements were very different so I'm answering for others that are coming here looking for answers rather than answering the exact question and requirements posted here.

**My requirements:**

- It needed to match against multiple paths inside the same string
- Each path was known to start with either `./` or `../`
- It could not use look behinds because they were not supported
- It was known that each path would be on a new line
- Folders would always be separated using single `/` characters.

This is what I came up with (based on JS RegEx syntax):

> **My solution**
>
> `/\.\.?\/[^\n"?:*<>|]+\.[A-z0-9]+/g`

I'll explain it using this as an example:

> ../path/to/file.ext lorem ipsum text

- `/..../g` means the regex will match multiple times inside the same string
- `\.\.?\/` matches both `../` and `./`

  > `/\.\.?\//g`
  >
  > `../`path/to/file.ext lorem ipsum text
- `[^\n"?:*<>|]+` is a black list of characters that do not match.

  - `[^....]` = do not match against this list of characters.
  - `\n` = new line (paths would never appear on the same line)
  - all the other characters are literal. They are illegal file name characters.

    > `/\.\.?\/[^\n"?:*<>|]+/g`
    >
    > `../path/to/file.ext lorem ipsum text`
- `\.[A-z0-9]+` is to make sure that it stops at the end of the file extension.

  > `/\.\.?\/[^\n"?:*<>|]+\.[A-z0-9]+/g`
  >
  > `../path/to/file.ext` lorem ipsum text